# Problems with ESLint arrow-body when replacing it without block

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I know that the question is elsewhere, but it does not work for me.

### Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; parenthesize the returned value and move it immediately after the `=>`  arrow-body-style##

I tried it:

```
  changePage(id) {
    this.setState(prevState, props => (...prevState, selectedPageId: id));
    };
  }
```

Return the following message: 'prevState' is declared but its value is never read.

The original code:

```
  changePage(id) {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      return { ...prevState, selectedPageId: id };
    });
  }
```

Solve that ESLint problem without ignoring the validation.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be

```
changePage = id => {
   this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, selectedPageId: id }));
};
```

I did 2 things here

- changePage = id => {} (this ensures that `this` is binded properly to it's lexcial context in the function)
- `this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, selectedPageId: id }))` properly returns an object

Comment: Thank you! It worked and I already understood how to do it in the next few occasions.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to put parenthesis around your callback's input values if there are more than a single one.

You also have to surround your returned value with brackets to indicate that you want to return a JSON object :

```
changePage(id) {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({ ...prevState, selectedPageId: id }))
};
```

But since you are not using the `props` variable anyway, you can shorten the syntax. Converting your function to an arrow function will also automatically bind it :

```
changePage = id => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, selectedPageId: id }))
};
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked and I already understood how to do it in the next few occasions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed babel in your VS Code extension then uninstall it . It will resolve the error .